# post web request

Tags: web-applications, webforms, httpwebrequest

I have a problem in posting parameters to a server... 
as I know that when I send a request like the following: `http://www.xxxxx.xxx?var1=**&var2=**&...etc.`
parameters var1 and var2 till var(n) must be in the form tag...

```
<input type=hidden name=var1 value="10"/>
<input type=text name=var2 value="sami"/>
```

and so on..

But I faced one web site that expect some parameters that are not in the form
The exact form:

```
<form method="POST" name="snd" action="a2b.php">
...
    <input type="image" value="ok" name="s1" id="btn_ok" 
               class="dynamic_img"  src="img/x.gif" alt="تمام"/>
</form>
```

here this post sends parameters  `a2b.php?...&s1.x=10&s1.y=20`

but there is no any inputs named s1.x or s1.y in this form.
Is it possible to put parameters in the form of (var.var)?

Comment: Are you talking about extracting parameters in the QueryString of a Get in PHP or parameters from a form that was submitted via a Post and are thus possibly stored somewhere else?  Please clarify what you are using as there are dozens of different ways to process a web form you do realize, right?

Comment: I want to know the values of the parameters s1.x and s1.y

Comment: Those parameters are not found in the form... so I want to know how the browser sends them, and from where they had come..

Comment: for normal parameters I can extract them and get their values easily... I'm using c# and Agile library to get the HtmlElements in the document I'm interest of. then I read the attributes of the elements that I chose.

Answer (score 0):

That's what an image button is sending when you use it to post the form. There should be an `input` with `type="image"` and `name="s1"`.

Comment: yes there is input with type="image" and name="s1" but I cannot reach s1.x or s1.y from where they had come? I'm Firebug to inspect the sent header parameters.. but when I check the real document I don't find them..